# Two denim hijabs

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

When fellow Finns ask me which hockey team I support, here's what I tell them:

> A singer inhabits the lesser of two denim hijabs.

What is the name of my favourite team?

Comment: Just commenting say I really support the imagery and idea of “Denim Hijabs.”

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A shot at this is your team is

> **[Ilves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilves)**

A singer inhabits the lesser of two denim hijabs is a roundabout description of:

> Elvis - lives - evils - Levis - veils, are anagrams of matching/following words.

Comment: Elvis lives????

Comment: Elvis was just spotted in Vegas. A few hundred of them :)